# C# webservices with SQLite

Tags: c#, web-services, sqlite

I have created Web services in C#(to add data into SQLite database). After running the project i am getting this message on Service1.asmx page

```
Finisar.SQLite.SQLiteException: Valid parameters:
Data Source=&lt;database file&gt;  (required)
Version=&lt;version of SQLite (2 or 3)&gt;  (default: 2)
New=True|False  (default: False)
Compress=True|False  (default: False)
UTF8Encoding=True|False  (default: False)
UTF16Encoding=True|False  (default: False)
Cache Size=&lt;N&gt;  (default: 2000)
Synchronous=Full|Normal|Off  (default: Normal)
DateTimeFormat=ISO8601|Ticks|CurrentCulture  (default: ISO8601)
Compatibility=[old-date-format][,old-binary-format] (default: None)
   at Finisar.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.Open()
   at WebService3.Service1.setConnection() in d:\MiniProject2013\ConsoleApplication2\WebService3\Service1.asmx.cs:line 39`enter code here`
   at WebService3.Service1.addUser(String id, String fname, String lname, String phone, String email, String lag, String log) in d:\MiniProject2013\ConsoleApplication2\WebService3\Service1.asmx.cs:line 53
```

Please suggest me what to do

Comment: I would suggest using a debugger to step through your application instead of running it to see what errors you get. I would guess from the error that your connection string is wrong and SQLite can't open a connection to your database file.

Comment: Looks like you haven't specified a `Data Source` in the connection string or one of your connection string parameters are invalid, posting the connection string would help...

Comment: The Finisar.SQLite provider is telling you that you are using an invalid parameter. Show your `setConnection` code.

Comment: Depending on the aims of your application I would not recommend SQLite. It's fine for local applications with only one user accessing it (at a time) but with a remote system which potentially can be accessed by multiple users it's not a good choice.

Comment: @James: Here is the connection                                    string  SQLiteConnection sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=test.db;Pooling=true;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;FailIfMissing=false;");